# Kubernetes Deployment dynamic port forwarding

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I am moving a Docker Image from Docker to a K8s Deployment. I have auto-scale rules on so it starts 5 but can go to 12. The Docker image on K8s starts perfectly with a k8s service in front to cluster the Deployment.

Now each container has its own JVM which has a Prometheus app retrieving its stats. In Docker, this is no problem because the port that serves Prometheus info is dynamically created with a starting port of 8000, so the docker-compose.yml grows the port by 1 based on how many images are started.

The problem is that I can't find how to do this in a K8s [deployment].yml file. Because Deployment pods are dynamic, I would have thought there would be some way to set a starting HOST port to be incremented based on how many containers are started.

Maybe I am looking at this the wrong way so any clarification would be helpful meanwhile will keep searching the Google for any info on such a thing.

Comment: I can't tell why you would need this from this setup. Deployment replicas lead to multiple pods, not multiple containers within one pod. If you are doing something with templating to create dynamic containers in a pod (which I doubt) then it would be up to your templating system to do this. Otherwise it's not necessary (or normal) to use different ports as each pod has its own cluster IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after reading and reading and reading so much I came to the conclusion that K8s is not responsible to open ports for a Docker Image or provide ingress to your app on some weird port, it's not its responsibility. K8s Deployment just deploys the Pods you requested. You can set the Ports option on a DEPLOYMENT -> SPEC -> CONTAINERS -> PORTS which just like Docker is only informational. But this allows you to JSONPath query for all PODS(containers) with a Prometheus port available. This will allow you to rebuild the "targets" value in Prometheus.yaml file. Now having those targets makes them available to Grafana to create a dashboard.

That's it, pretty easy. I was complicating something because I did not understand it. I am including a script I QUICKLY wrote to get something going  USE AT YOUR OWN RISK.

By the way, I use Pod and Container interchangeably.

```
  #!/usr/bin/env bash
  #set -x

  _MyappPrometheusPort=8055
  _finalIpsPortArray=()
  _prometheusyamlFile=prometheus.yml

  cd /docker/images/prometheus


  #######################################################################################################################################################
  #One container on the K8s System is weave and it holds the subnet we need to validate against.
  #weave-net-lwzrk                            2/2     Running   8 (7d3h ago)   9d    192.168.2.16   accl-ffm-srv-006   <none>           <none>
  _weavenet=$(kubectl get pod -n kube-system -o wide | grep weave | cut -d ' ' -f1 )
  echo "_weavenet: $_weavenet"

  #The default subnet is the one that lets us know the conntainer is part of kubernetes network.
  #          Range: 10.32.0.0/12
  #  DefaultSubnet: 10.32.0.0/12
  _subnet=$( kubectl exec -n kube-system $_weavenet -c weave -- /home/weave/weave --local status | sed -En "s/^(.*)(DefaultSubnet:\s)(.*)?/\3/p" )
  echo "_subnet: $_subnet"
  _cidr2=$( echo "$_subnet" | cut -d '/' -f2 )
  echo "_cidr2: /$_cidr2"



  #######################################################################################################################################################
  #This is an array of the currently monitored containers that prometheus was sstarted with.
  #We will remove any containers form the array that fit the K8s Weavenet subnet with the myapp prometheus port.
  _targetLineFound_array=($( egrep '^\s{1,20}-\s{0,5}targets\s{0,5}:\s{0,5}\[.*\]' $_prometheusyamlFile | sed -En "s/(.*-\stargets:\s\[)(.*)(\]).*/\2/p"  | tr "," "\n"))
  for index in "${_targetLineFound_array[@]}"
  do
      _ip="${index//\'/$''}"
      _ipTocheck=$( echo $_ip | cut -d ':' -f1 )
      _portTocheck=$( echo $_ip | cut -d ':' -f2 )
      #We need to check if the IP is within the subnet mask attained from K8s.
      #The port must also be the prometheus port in case some other port is used also for Prometheus.
      #This means the IP should be removed since we will put the list of IPs from
      #K8s currently in production by Deployment/AutoScale rules.
      #Network:   10.32.0.0/12
      _isIpWithinSubnet=$( ipcalc $_ipTocheck/$_cidr2 | sed -En "s/^(.*)(Network:\s+)([0-9]{1}[0-9]?[0-9]?\.[0-9]{1}[0-9]?[0-9]?\.[0-9]{1}[0-9]?[0-9]?\.[0-9]{1}[0-9]?[0-9]?)(\/[0-9]{1}[0-9]{1}.*)?/\3/p" )
      if [[ "$_isIpWithinSubnet/$_cidr2" == "$_subnet" && "$_portTocheck" == "$_MyappPrometheusPort" ]]; then
          echo "IP managed by K8s will be deleted: _isIpWithinSubnet: ($_ip) $_isIpWithinSubnet"
      else
          _finalIpsPortArray+=("$_ip")
      fi
  done



  #######################################################################################################################################################
  #This is an array of the current running myapp App containers with a prometheus port that is available.
  #From this list we will add them to the prometheus file to be available for Grafana monitoring.
  readarray -t _currentK8sIpsArr < <( kubectl get pods --all-namespaces --chunk-size=0 -o json | jq '.items[] | select(.spec.containers[].ports != null) | select(.spec.containers[].ports[].containerPort == '$_MyappPrometheusPort' ) | .status.podIP' )
  for index in "${!_currentK8sIpsArr[@]}"
  do
      _addIPToMonitoring=${_currentK8sIpsArr[index]//\"/$''}
      echo "IP Managed by K8s as myapp app with prometheus currently running will be added to monitoring: $_addIPToMonitoring"
      _finalIpsPortArray+=("$_addIPToMonitoring:$_MyappPrometheusPort")
  done



  ######################################################################################################################################################
  #we need to recreate this string and sed it into the file
  #- targets: ['192.168.2.13:3201', '192.168.2.13:3202', '10.32.0.7:8055', '10.32.0.8:8055']

  _finalPrometheusTargetString="- targets: ["
  i=0

  # Iterate the loop to read and print each array element
  for index in "${!_finalIpsPortArray[@]}"
  do
      ((i=i+1))
      _finalPrometheusTargetString="$_finalPrometheusTargetString '${_finalIpsPortArray[index]}'"
      if [[ $i != ${#_finalIpsPortArray[@]}  ]]; then
           _finalPrometheusTargetString="$_finalPrometheusTargetString,"
      fi
  done

  _finalPrometheusTargetString="$_finalPrometheusTargetString]"

  echo "$_finalPrometheusTargetString"

  sed -i -E "s/(.*)-\stargets:\s\[.*\]/\1$_finalPrometheusTargetString/" ./$_prometheusyamlFile

  docker-compose down
  sleep 4
  docker-compose up -d

  echo "All changes were made. Exiting"

  exit 0
```

Comment: Is your Prometheus deployed in a way that you don't have the PodMonitor and ServiceMonitor types? They're made for this.

Comment: Jason S please read the post and understand it before commenting

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you should be using the Average of JVM across all the replicas. There is no meaning to create a different deployment with a different **port** if you are running the single **same Docker image** across all the **replicas**.

i think keeping a single deployment with resource requirements set to deployment would be the best practice.

You can get the **JVM** average of all the running replicas

```
sum(jvm_memory_max_bytes{area="heap", app="app-name",job="my-job"}) / sum(kube_pod_status_phase{phase="Running"})
```

as you are running the same Docker image across all replicas and K8s service by default will be managing the Load Balancing, average utilization would be an option to monitor.

Still, if you want to filter and get different values you can create different **deployments** (Not at all good way) or use the **stateful sets**.

You can also filter the data by **hostname (POD name)** in Prometheus, so will get the each replica usage.

Comment: Harsh, You have some good points, but I have to disagree at a higher level, as an admin you  
 don't get to pick clients' Docker images. K8s states all docker images can run. The image runs but it has some extra requirements. The client says they need the individual JVM's stats because they have an issue with the code. But with not being able to get dynamic port-forwarding they cannot monitor what they need to monitor. I get what you are saying but "Client is king". It would be easy to tell the client to come back when they have their Image fixed but reality says that will not happen.

Comment: i do agree, and you are also right. As i was not aware about the code issue. If memory leak and all that happening yes you need single replica stats but above mentioned scenario is for general use case. If code has issue i would suggest creating dashboard filter by replica name that would be best if you can. If you have issue make different deployment or statefulsets.